# Подключение LightOpenID в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Следовал инструкции с этой ссылки
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/482228/how-to-use-light-open-id-on-laravel-4-framework

Но после отправки POST запроса laravel сообщает об ошибке "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LightOpenID' not found"

Файл с классом openid я закачал и директория lightopenid находится в директории vendor. Вероятно laravel ищет класс не в том месте, но как указать правильные пути я не знаю, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так он же вам говорит что ищет файл по пути: `App\Http\Controllers\LightOpenID`.

Пакет вообще очень старый и подключается он простым инклудом файла:

```
require 'openid.php';
```

И потом нужно указывать у себя что `LightOpenID` находиться в корне, то есть вместо:

```
$opID = new LightOpenID('yourdomain.tld');
```

Использовать:

```
$opID = new \LightOpenID('yourdomain.tld');
```

Ещё учитывайте что инструкция для 4 версии фреймворка, который многим отличается от 5 версии.

Comment: Спасибо, ты лучший.) Я пробовал require раньше, но с ним не работало , а вот $opID = new \LightOpenID('yourdomain.tld'); зарешало.

Comment: @LordySL require не нужен если ставили через composer.

Comment: И вправду, спасибо еще раз.)